# Codeigniter3 filter query results to keep rows where a column value is not one of two values

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, if-statement, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter website where I am displaying some values using a `foreach()`. I am trying to ignore specific values from database.

I wrote the following code:

```
$res="select * from paymentform order by id desc limit 1000";
$query = $this->db->query($res);
foreach ($query->result_array() as $re) {
    if($re['authstatus']!='success' || $re['authstatus']!='0300'){
        // some processing
    }
}
```

The issue is that the columns containing `success` or `0300` are not being filtered out.

Comment: I wonder if you filter your query at the SQL level, does it work? Maybe try SELECT * FROM paymentform WHERE authstatus NOT IN ('success','0300');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with filtering in PHP (after you have limited the total rows to 1000) is that your resultant array will have an inconsistent number of rows.

If you build your filtration logic into your query, you will have a better chance of hitting that 1000 limit.  As others have mentioned, you made a basic mistake in your condition logic regarding "and" and "or" operators.  An `authstatus` of `0300` satisfies the first condtion (`$re['authstatus']!='success'`).

Let's avoid it altogether with a refined query using CI3's query builder methods.

CI3 Model Code:

```
$result = $this->db
    ->from("paymentform")
    ->where_not_in("authstatus", ["success", "0300"])
    ->order_by("id", "DESC")
    ->limit(1000);
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

The `select()` method is not needed when you want to return all columns from the table. Now you can feed `$result` to your `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

change your if to this

```
if($re['authstatus']!='success' && $re['authstatus']!='0300')
```

Comment: Why should OP do that? What was causing a problem? How does your code fix this? Please add some explanation to answers

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to get all condition in your if statement, you must using '&&' not '||'
We know that statement has different function, when you using || it will ignore some condition when there are 1 condition has true value. But, when you using && it will be checked one by one your condition untill all condition has true.
Let's try implemented into your code from this ...

```
if($re['authstatus']!='success' || $re['authstatus']!='0300'){
    ................................
}
```

To this...

```
if($re['authstatus']!='success' && $re['authstatus']!='0300'){
    ................................
}
```

The meaning is, when `$re['authstatus']!='success'` it will checked again another condition `$re['authstatus']!='0300'`